# Prepared statement returns false but row is inserted?

Tags: java, mysql, sql, prepared-statement

So this is my table:

```
mysql> DESCRIBE app_user;
+----------+-------------+------+-----+---------+----------------+
| Field    | Type        | Null | Key | Default | Extra          |
+----------+-------------+------+-----+---------+----------------+
| id       | int(11)     | NO   | PRI | NULL    | auto_increment |
| username | varchar(40) | NO   | PRI | NULL    |                |
| password | varchar(40) | NO   |     | NULL    |                |
| email    | varchar(40) | NO   | PRI | NULL    |                |
+----------+-------------+------+-----+---------+----------------+
4 rows in set

mysql>
```

What I am expecting is that, I should not be able to add 2 rows with same username because username is Primary Key..

And this is my Java Code:

```
@Test
public void shouldNotInsertWithSameUserName() throws IOException, SQLException {
    AppUserAccessObject appUserAccessObject = new AppUserAccessObject(new DatabaseConnectionImpl());
    Assert.assertFalse(appUserAccessObject.insertUser("koray", "email", "password"));
}
```

So this test passes, which means insertUser returns false.. However when I check the database, I see a new row insterted. What am I doing wrong? And the insertuser:

```
public boolean insertUser(String username,String email,String password) throws SQLException {
    PreparedStatement preparedStatement = connection.prepareStatement("INSERT INTO "+ tableName + "(username,email,password) VALUES(?,?,?)");
    preparedStatement.setString(1,username);
    preparedStatement.setString(2,email);
    preparedStatement.setString(3,password);
    boolean execute = preparedStatement.execute();
    return execute;
}
```

Comment: You misunderstood the return value of PreparedStatement#execute(). Please read carefully http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/sql/PreparedStatement.html#execute%28%29

Answer (score 15, accepted):

Your primary key is based on 3 fields:

- id (which has auto increment value)
- username
- email

So, the primary key restricts a new row with these 3 fields having the same value. But since `id` is marked on auto increment and you're always sending `null` to it, it will generate a new value, thus never having these three fields with the same value.

A better design for your table would be having `id` as primary key only, and an [Unique Key](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Unique_key) for your `username` and `email` fields. In fact, it would be even better having two unique keys: one for `username` and another for `email`.

This will do it:

```
CREATE TABLE app_user (
    id INT PRIMARY KEY AUTO_INCREMENT,
    username varchar(40),
    password varchar(40),
    email varchar(40),
    UNIQUE KEY (username),
    UNIQUE KEY (email)
);
```

---

Apart from the design problem in your database:

- Use [`PreparedStatement#executeUpdate`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/sql/PreparedStatement.html#executeUpdate%28%29) to execute DML statemens like `INSERT`, `UPDATE` and `DELETE`.
- Use [`PreparedStatement#executeQuery`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/sql/PreparedStatement.html#executeQuery%28%29) when retrieving data from database through a `SELECT`.
- Use [`PreparedStatement#execute`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/sql/PreparedStatement.html#execute%28%29) when performing any kind of SQL statement like `CREATE TABLE` or `ALTER TABLE`.

---

> Prepared statement returns false but row is inserted?

From `PreparedStatement#execute` javadoc:

> Returns: `true` if the first result is a `ResultSet` object; `false` if the first result is an update count or there is no result.

In this case, you got a `false` result since you executed an update operation (`INSERT` is understood as an update operation).